# Use signed or unsigned char in constructing CString?

Tags: c++, string, mfc

I am check the [document for CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx#cstringt__cstringt) . In the following statement:

> - `CStringT( LPCSTR lpsz )`: Constructs a Unicode `CStringT` from an ANSI string. You can also use this constructor to load a string resource as shown in the example below.
> - `CStringT( LPCWSTR lpsz )`: Constructs a `CStringT` from a Unicode string.
> - `CStringT( const unsigned char* psz )`: Allows you to construct a `CStringT` from a pointer to `unsigned char`.

I have some questions:

1. Why are there two versions, one for `const char*` (`LPCSTR`) and one for `unsigned char*`? Which version should I use for different cases? For example, does `CStringT("Hello")` use the first or second version? When getting a null-terminated string from a third-party, such as `sqlite3_column_text()` ([see here](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)), should I convert it to `char*` or `unsigned char *`? ie, should I use `CString((LPCSTR)sqlite3_column_text(...))` or `CString(sqlite3_column_text(...))`? It seems that both will work, is that right?
2. Why does the `char*` version construct a "Unicode" `CStringT` but the `unsigned char*` version will construct a `CStringT`? `CStringT` is a templated class to indicate all 3 instances, ie, `CString`, `CStringA`, `CStringW`, so why the emphasis on "Unicode" `CStringT` when constructing using `LPCSTR` (`const char*`)?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `CStringT` is a class, and classes don't exist in C, so this is definitely C++ only

Answer (score 3):

`LPCSTR` is just `const char*`, not `const signed char*`.  `char` is signed or unsigned depending on compiler implementation, but `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are 3 distinct types for purposes of overloading. String literals in C++ are of type `const char[]`, so `CStringT("Hello")` will always use the `LPCSTR` constructor, never the `unsigned char*` constructor.

`sqlite3_column_text(...)` returns `unsigned char*` because it returns UTF-8 encoded text.  I don't know what the `unsigned char*` constructor of `CStringT` actually does (it has something to do with MBCS strings), but the `LPCSTR` constructor performs a conversion from ANSI to UNICODE using the user's default locale.  That would destroy UTF-8 text that contains non-ASCII characters.

Your best option in that case is to convert the UTF-8 text to UTF-16 (using `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent, or simply using `sqlite3_column_text16()` instead, which returns UTF-16 encoded text), and then use the `LPCWSTR` (`const wchar_t*`) constructor of `CStringT`, as Windows uses `wchar_t` for UTF-16 data.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: Use either of the following:

- `CStringW value( sqlite3_column_text16() );` (optionally setting SQLite's internal encoding to UTF-16), or
- `CStringW value( CA2WEX( sqlite3_column_text(), CP_UTF8 ) );`

Everything else is just not going to work out, one way or another.

---

First things first: [CStringT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class) is a class **template**, parameterized (among others) on the character type it uses to represent the stored sequence. This is passed as the `BaseType` template type argument. There are 2 concrete template instantiations, `CStringA` and `CStringW`, that use `char` and `wchar_t` to store the sequence of characters, respectively<sup>1</sup>.

`CStringT` exposes the following [predefined types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#cstringt-predefined-types) that describe the properties of the template instantiation:

- `XCHAR`: Character type used to store the sequence.
- `YCHAR`: Character type that an instance can be converted from/to.

The following table shows the concrete types for `CStringA` and `CStringW`:

```
         | XCHAR   | YCHAR
---------+---------+--------
CStringA | char    | wchar_t
CStringW | wchar_t | char
```

While the storage of the `CStringT` instantiations make no restrictions with respect to the character encoding being used, the conversion c'tors and operators are implemented based on the following assumptions:

- `char` represents ANSI<sup>2</sup> encoded code units.
- `whcar_t` represents UTF-16 encoded code units.

If your program doesn't match those assumptions, it is strongly advised to disable implicit wide-to-narrow and narrow-to-wide conversions. To do this, defined the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` preprocessor symbol prior to including any ATL/MFC header files. Doing so is recommended even if your program meets the assumptions to prevent accidental conversions, that are both costly as well as potentially destructive.

With that out of the way, let's move on to the questions:

> Why are there two versions, one for `const char*` (`LPCSTR`) and one for `unsigned char*`?

That's easy: Convenience. The overload simply allows you to construct a `CString` instance irrespective of the signedness of the character type<sup>3</sup>. The implementation of the overload taking a `const unsigned char*` argument 'forwards' to the c'tor taking a `const char*`:

```
CSTRING_EXPLICIT CStringT(_In_z_ const unsigned char* pszSrc) :
    CThisSimpleString( StringTraits::GetDefaultManager() )
{
    *this = reinterpret_cast< const char* >( pszSrc );
}
```

> Which version should I use for different cases?

It doesn't matter, as long as you are constructing a `CStringA`, i.e. no conversion is applied. If you are constructing a `CStringW`, you shouldn't be using either of those (as explained above).

> For example, does `CStringT("Hello")` use the first or second version?

`"Hello"` is of type `const char[6]`, that decays into a `const char*` to the first element in the array, when passed to the `CString` c'tor. It calls the overload taking a `const char*` argument.

> When getting a null-terminated string from a third-party, such as `sqlite3_column_text()` ([see here](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)), should I convert it to `char*` or `unsigned char *`? ie, should I use `CString((LPCSTR)sqlite3_column_text(...))` or `CString(sqlite3_column_text(...))`?

SQLite assumes UTF-8 encoding in this case. `CStringA` *can* store UTF-8 encoded text, but it's really, **really** dangerous to do so. `CStringA` assumes ANSI encoding, and readers of your code likely will do, too. It is recommended to either change your SQLite database to store UTF-16 (and use `sqlite_column_text16`) to construct a `CStringW`. If that is not feasible, manually convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 before storing the data in a `CStringW` instance using the [CA2WEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ca2wex-class) macro:

```
CStringW data( CA2WEX( sqlite3_column_text(), CP_UTF8 ) );
```

> It seems that both will work, is that right?

That's not correct. Neither one works as soon as you get non-ASCII characters from your database.

> Why does the `char*` version construct a "Unicode" `CStringT` but the `unsigned char*` version will construct a `CStringT`?

That looks to be the result of documentation trying to be compact. A `CStringT` is a class template. It is neither Unicode nor does it even exist. I'm guessing that remark section on the [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#cstringt) is meant to highlight the ability to construct Unicode strings from ANSI input (and vice versa). This is briefly mentioned, too (*"Note that some of these constructors act as conversion functions."*).

To sum this up, here is a list of generic advice when using MFC/ATL strings:

- Prefer using `CStringW`. This is the only string type whose implied character encoding is unambiguous (UTF-16).
- Use `CStringA` only, when interfacing with legacy code. Make sure to unambiguously note the character encoding used. Also make sure to understand that *"currently active locale"* can change at any time. See [Keep your eye on the code page: Is this string CP_ACP or UTF-8?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150611-00/?p=45401) for more information.
- **Never** use `CString`. Just by looking at code, it's no longer clear, what type this is (could be any of 2 types). Likewise, when looking at a constructor invocation, it is no longer possible to see, whether this is a copy or conversion operation.
- Disable implicit conversions for the `CStringT` class template instantiations.

---

<sup>1</sup> *There's also `CString` that uses the generic-text mapping [`TCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/working-with-strings#tchars) as its `BaseType`. `TCHAR` expands to either `char` or `wchar_t`, depending preprocessor symbols. `CString` is thus an alias for either `CStringA` or `CStringW` depending on those very same preprocessor symbols. **Unless you are targeting Win9x, don't use any of the generic-text mappings.***

<sup>2</sup> *Unlike Unicode encodings, ANSI is not a self-contained representation. Interpretation of code units depends on external state (the currently active locale). **Do not use unless you are interfacing with legacy code.***

<sup>3</sup> *It is implementation defined, whether `char` is interpreted as signed or unsigned. Either way, `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` are 3 distinct types. By default, Visual Studio interprets `char` as signed.*